# How to format display String to currency in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, format, currency

I need to format my display tostring results to a currency in C#

```
display = "Service Amount: " + service + "<br>" +   
          "Discount Amount: " + discountAmount + "<br>" +
          "Total: " + total + "<br>";
        lblDisplay.Text = display;
```

I did try the following:

```
display = "Service Amount: " + Console.Write(int.ToString("c",service)) + "
```

but I couldn't figure out what variables to put in. I just need it to display as $35.00 after the it returns the string.

Comment: service.ToString("C") - See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: `display = "Service Amount: " + service.ToString("C");`

Comment: Awesome thanks so much! Y'all answered it can't believe it was that easy!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
display = string.Format("Service Amount: {0}",service.ToString("C"));
Console.WriteLine(display);
```

You can also look at [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) for building strings or [String.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format("Service Amount: {0:C}<br>", service)
```